# How to show message "No results found" for table research?

Tags: javascript, html, spring, thymeleaf

I'm doing a simply project on intellij with spring boot and i did a table with an input for the searches. What I want is to show a message whene the search fails and no results are found. How can I do it?

This is my table:

```
<div>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">
<table id="tablePatients" width="100%" border="1px solid black" class="table table-striped">
    <thead class = "thead-dark">
    <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Cognome</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="mytable">
    <tr th:each="patient : ${allPatients}">
    <td th:text="${patient.id}">1</td>
    <td th:text="${patient.name}">w</td>
    <td th:text="${patient.surname}">e</td>
    <td> <a href="show?id=10" th:href="@{show(idPatient=${patient.id} , idDoctor=${doctor.id})}"> show </a></td>
    <td> <a href="addPrescription?id=10" th:href="@{newPrescription(idPatient=${patient.id} , idDoctor=${doctor.id})}"> add prescription </a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

And this is the script I use for the research:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myInput").on("keyup", function () { //here #input textbox id
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#mytable tr").filter(function () { //here #table table body id
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you tags should be more precise. It's more a question about jquery and/or whatever templating engine you use. Maybe thymeleaf?

Answer (score 1):

The question is, how can you do that in the templating engine you use. It's not really a Spring question, or HTML or JavaScript for that matter.

You should be able to check if `allPatients` is empty and then render something. If you use [thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/) and want to do it server side:

```
<tr th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(allPatients)}">
  <td>no patients found...</td>
</tr>
<tr th:each="patient : ${allPatients}">
...
```

If you want to do it in the JavaScript logic, you posted, which looks like it uses jQuery, do something like this:

- after filtering the rows, check if the result is empty
- if so, add another row to render the empty message, e.g.:

```
$('#mytable').append('<tr id="empty-message"><td>no patients found...</td></tr>');
```

- if the result is not empty, remove `#empty-message`

Alternativley, you can always add the row, but use `show()` and `hide()` insteaf of append and remove.